# echo string with special chars doesn't appear correctly

Tags: php

The correct string is Culto Mensal Área Vila Mariana but it appears Culto Mensal Ãrea Vila Mariana ....
Gratidão =  GratidÃ£o

I have already tried with htmlspecialchars function

```
<?php
    include "mysqlconecta.php"; // Conecta ao banco de dados
    $result=mysql_query("select * from CDEventos");
    echo "<table width=900 border=\"2\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Titulo</td>";
    echo "<td>Local</td>";
    echo "<td>Data</td>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['titulo']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['local']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['data']."</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href=\"altera.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Alterar</a>"; 
    echo  "&nbsp&nbsp";
    echo "<a href=\"deletar.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Excluir</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Dont use **mysql_*** - It's **deprecated**, use `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the content as `UTF-8`.

Use either:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in PHP or

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

in html within the `head` tags.

Also, as a side note:

Please don't continue using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Please look into `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Please also look at Niet's answer regarding database structure and connection too, as you should always be looking into that too! @ProappAplicativos

Answer (score 1):

Your string is in UTF8, you must therefore handle it as UTF8.

You need to set UTF8 in:

- The database structure (column collation)
- The database *connection* (a lot of people forget this)
- The page itself (`charset=utf-8` as in BeatAlex's answer)

*ALL THREE* must be set correctly.